# Alphabetize using I/O in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use an I/O and sort the input file alphabetically using a method called alphabetize, this has a compile error

> (35,42): error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What can I do to resolve that?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace examplefile
{
    class examplefile
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            StreamWriter writer = null;

            writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\C#Files\OutputWrite2.txt");

            Console.SetOut(writer);

            Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(@"C:\C#Files\InputRead2.txt"));

            string letters;
            while ((letters = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            writer.Close();


            StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
            standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
            Console.SetOut(standardOutput);

            Console.WriteLine("Sorted all letters alphabetically and wrote to output file.");

        }

        public static String alphabetize(string letters)
        {
            char[] alphabetize = letters.ToArray();
            Array.Sort(alphabetize);
            return new string(alphabetize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is producing the error?  And can you provide the entire error text (in your question, not here in the comments)

Comment: (35,42): error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method
        'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
        assembly reference?)

Comment: Just [edit] your question ...

Comment: Did you even read my entire comment?  Your *question itself* should contain the error message.  Don't put substantive information in the comments; put it in your question.  Also, what line does the error get thrown on?

Comment: Maybe it is wise to take the [tour], visit [ask] and use the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Try adding `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
char[] alphabetize = letters.ToArray();
```

As the error you got clearly states:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension
>   method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be
>   found

There are two parts to this error message.  The first part says that `string` doesn't have a `ToArray()` method.  Since `letters` is a `string`, you can't call `ToArray()` on it.  Try this instead:

```
char[] alphabetize = letters.ToCharArray();
```

The second part of the error tells you that there is no `ToArray` extension method defined in the context; however, the `System.Linq` namespace has an extension method `ToArray<TSource>()` on the interface `IEnumerable<char>`.  `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so if you include the `System.Linq` namespace in your file, then you *can* call the extension method `ToArray<TSource>()`:

```
// at the top of your file with your other includes.
using System.Text;

// NOW you can do this:
char[] alphabetize = letters.ToArray();
```

Comment: `ToArray` would work if Linq is included since `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`